# list all on search in lookup!

Tags: salesforce1-app, lookup, list-view, search

I have in my business salesforce1 an object that has a Lookup to the object car. When I click on the magnifying glass to choose a car, this just shows me the cars that I've visualized. It is possible to change this so I see them all? 
How can I do this?

Thank you all!

Comment: Mario, by default lookup filters page, list views page shows recent records and you have to search for what record you want to see. can you add more details to your question, maybe a screenshot will be good.

Answer (score 2):

"Search All" is a dangerous behavior vis-a-vis performance.

To minimize the impact of lots of users constantly doing this, salesforce does not allow open searches (or searches without criteria) in lookups and dialogs. In fact, most require at least two (non-wildcard) characters minimum to function, unless you build it using custom Visualforce and Apex.

This is a trade-off that is sometimes required to be made...not quite as nice UX, but much more performant platform.

Comment: Just to add that the "Search All" is even a worse idea when it comes to a mobile platform. On a mobile device, you got to respect the available data/bandwidth of the user and use it as sparingly as possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to view all records in lookup dialog box. Only the recently viewed records are shown by default. You can set some filter criteria for lookup field if you want to see a  list of particular type of cars.